# The trivial metric and convergence

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

The following question is probably rather naive, so I apologize beforehand.

> In class we defined the trivial metric $d$ as follows:

> $$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x = y \\ 
> 1 & \mbox{if } x \ne y \end{cases}  $$

> It was said, that in any space endowed with the trivial metric every sequence converges.

I do not understand why this is true.

If I am not mistaken convergence in this metric requires that a sequence has to be eventually constant; i.e. the values of the sequence have to be constant after a certain index. But this contradicts the claim that every sequence converges.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, and the source you cited isn't. In fact, if a sequence is not constant eventually, then it can't be Cauchy because $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x_{n+1})=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I got one last question: According to wikipedia (link in the comment below) in the trivial topology every sequence converges. I understand this statement and why it is true. But I am confused by the following: The trvial topology should be induced by the trivial metric  (if I am not mistaken) then why is the above statement true for the trivial topology but not for the trivial metric?

Comment: Here the link to the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology

Comment: @3nondatur The trivial topology - say, $\tau=\{\emptyset, X\}$ - is not metrizable (unless $X=\{x\}$). In fact, the usual name of your metric is "*discrete* metric", because it induces the *discrete* topology (id est, $\tau=\mathcal P(X)$). I don't know the reason behind the choice of terminology in your source.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot for your help.